# Issues copying an array of objects into another array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to copy an array of model objects which is part of an object that gets returned when making a RESt call into a local Array variable.  I created a GrnDetailModel and then created an empty Array array to copy the array into that gets returned by the REST Service...
When I try to copy the array into the Array variable I get the following error:  "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'GrnDetailModel[]'".  When I console.log the object that gets returned I can see that it's an array and not a string...  Any idea what could be causing this/how I can go about fixing it?

When I do the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.grn.GRNDetails.length; i++) {
    this.grnDetailList.push(this.grn.GRNDetails[i]);
}
```

it copies the array successfully but then I can't access any of the model class object's variables through the local variable e.g.

```
console.log(this.grnDetailList[i].barcode);
```

returns property 'barcode' does not exist on class GrnDetailModel...

my model:

```
export class GrnDetailModel {

    constructor(
        AccUnit: string, 
        Account: string,
        AutoCalc: boolean,
        BarCode : string,
        BranchIDKey: string,
        Branch_Name: string, 
        Branch_UserCode: string,    
        Charges: string,
        Comment: string,
        Confirmed: boolean,
        CostChanged: boolean,
        CostTax: string,    
        DiscExc: string,
        DiscInc: string,
        DiscInt: string,
        DiscNarr: string,
        DiscOrd: string,
        DiscountTemplate_Name: string,
        DiscountTemplate_UserCode: string,
        GPPerc: string,
        GRNDocument: null,
        GRNDocument_Comment: string,
        GRNDocument_UserCode: string,
        GrossCost: string,
        HeaderID: string,
        IDKey: string,
        NettCost: string,
        OrgCost: string,
        OrgPurchCount: string,  
        OrgSelling: string,
        PORDDetailIDKey: string,
        PriceListIDKey: string,
        PriceList_Name: string,
        PriceList_UserCode: string,
        ProductDetail_Name: string,
        ProductDetail_UserCode: string,
        ProductIDKey: string,
        Profit: string,
        PurchCount: string,
        PurchUOMIDKey: string,
        PurchUOM_Name: string,
        PurchUOM_UserCode: string,
        QtyDel: string,
        QtyOrd: string,
        ReturnTypeIDKey: string,
        ReturnType_Name: string, 
        ReturnType_UserCode: string,
        SellChanged: boolean,
        SellCount: string,
        SellingPrice: string,
        SellingTax: string,
        SellingUOMIDKey: string,
        SellingUOM_Name: string,
        SellingUOM_UserCode: string,
        Seq: string,
        ShortageTypeIDKey: string,
        ShortageType_Name: string,
        ShortageType_UserCode: string,
        SubGroupIDKey: string,
        SubGroup_Name: string,
        SubGroup_UserCode: string,
        SuppRef: string,
        SupplierCost: string,
        SupplierZone_Name: string,
        SupplierZone_UserCode: string,
        Target: string,
        TaxRateIDKey: string,
        TaxRate_Description: string,
        TaxRate_UserCode: string,
        TemplateIDKey: string,
        TimeStamp: string,
        TotAddTax: string,
        TotAddValue: string,
        TotalCost: string,
        TotalGP: string,
        TotalSelling: string,
        TotalStkQty: string,
        TotalWeight: string,
        Type: string,
        ZoneIDKey: string){}


}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `this.grnDetailList[i].BarCode` (capital B and C)

Comment: do you actually have anything else inside the `GrnDetailModel` class? because as it is now is preytty useless, you might just better use dynamic types - otherwise maybe you want to make those construct params members by using `private` or `public`?

Comment: You've defined `BarCode` in your *model* file, not `barcode`. Write this: `console.log(this.grnDetailList[i].BarCode);`

Comment: And how do you define your `grnDetailList` and `this.grn.GRNDetails`?

Comment: @John  grnDetailList: Array<GrnDetailModel> = [];

Comment: I did console.log BarCode and not barcode.

Comment: Each entry of `grn.GRNDetails`are also of type:`GrnDetailModel`?

Comment: It may be easier to help if you provide a plunkr or similar.

Comment: @John Yes.  I am trying to copy the returned array of GrnDetailModel objects into a local Array<GrnDetailModel>...  I also added the public access specifier in the model...

Comment: The reason I didn't add a plunkr is that it's quite big...

Comment: @John turns out notepad++ didn't save the changes to one of my models which caused this issue...  Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Glad you figured it out.